# addADX() and addTA(ADX(symbol)$ADX) yield different output

Tags: r, quantmod

```
chartSeries(HSI, subset="2017/", TA="addADX();addTA(ADX(HSI)$ADX,on=2,col=\"orange\")")
```

**output plot:**

[image]

The orange `ADX(HSI)$ADX` is off from the one shown by `addADX()`. What is the reason? Both functions should use the same arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ADX()` function requires a high-low-close series.  You're passing it an open-high-low-close series, so it uses the first 3 columns.  Use the `HLC()` extractor to subset only the columns you need to pass to `ADX()`.

```
chartSeries(HSI, subset = "2017/",
            TA = "addADX();addTA(ADX(HLC(HSI))$ADX, on = 2, col = 'orange')")
```